# System.AggregateException the program crashes

Tags: c#

I'm not sure exactly where the problem lies here, i think from searching it's in the "Parallel.ForEach" which is throwing the error, on a couple of systems the program runs fine but on my VPS the application crashes a few seconds in everytime.

```
    private void bgWorkerCheckURLs_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string action = e.Argument.ToString();
            if (action == "wraith_check_links")
            {
                int unidentified = 1;
                int identified = 1;

                Parallel.ForEach(dgView.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>(), (DataGridViewRow dataGridViewRow, ParallelLoopState parallelLoopState) =>
                {
                    var backgroundWorker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
                    if (backgroundWorker.CancellationPending)
                    {
                        e.Cancel = true;
                        parallelLoopState.Break();
                        toolStripStatusLabel.Text = "Cancelling...";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        List<string> urls;
                        string url = dataGridViewRow.Cells["url"].Value.ToString();
                        UrlRow urlRow = CheckUrl(url);
                        string platform = urlRow.Platform;
                        Invoke((Action)(() =>
                        {
                            dataGridViewRow.Cells["platform"].Value = platform;
                            dataGridViewRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = urlRow.BackColor;
                            dataGridViewRow.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = urlRow.ForeColor;
                            if (platform == "UNIDENTIFIED")
                            {
                                lblPlatformsUnIdentified.Text = unidentified.ToString();
                                Interlocked.Increment(ref unidentified);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                lblPlatformsIdentified.Text = identified.ToString();
                                Interlocked.Increment(ref identified);
                            }
                        }));
                        if (platforms.ContainsKey(platform))
                        {
                            urls = platforms[platform];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            urls = new List<string>();
                        }
                        urls.Add(url);
                        platforms[platform] = urls;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Helpers.returnMessage(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

The technical details are:

> Problem signature:
>
> Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
>
> Problem Signature 01:   wraithplatformidentifier.exe
>
> Problem Signature 02:   1.0.0.1
>
> Problem Signature 03:   563f8d36
>
> Problem Signature 04:   System
>
> Problem Signature 05:   4.0.30319.17929
>
> Problem Signature 06:   4ffa5c88
>
> Problem Signature 07:   23f8
>
> Problem Signature 08:   59
>
> Problem Signature 09:   System.AggregateException
>
> OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.274.10
>
> Locale ID:  1033
>
> Additional Information 1:   0a9e
>
> Additional Information 2:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
>
> Additional Information 3:   0a9e
>
> Additional Information 4:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

It only crashes on the VPS but it could possibly be on more systems if i left the error.

Can anyone see what i'm doing wrong?

thanks guys

Graham

Comment: It looks like it probably is thrown by the `Parallel.Foreach` code, but as you are only logging the exception message, not the stack trace, it's very hard to pinpoint exactly where the actual problem is.

Comment: @Rhumborl But he catches that exception and not throwing it forward - that should not happen.

Comment: @graham23s, If the code runs single threaded (simple `foreach` instead of `Parallel.ForEach`), would the app still crash?

Answer (score 0):

I see at least 3 potential places where the threading is not safe.

```
lblPlatformsUnIdentified.Text = unidentified.ToString();
lblPlatformsIdentified.Text = identified.ToString();
```

These controls could be being changed by different threads at the same time.

```
platforms[platform] = urls;
```

It looks like platforms is global list.  It is possible multiple threads could be trying to update the same index.

To quickly test this, create a global mutex:

```
System.Threading.Mutex mutex = new System.Threading.Mutex();
```

And put these lines around each of these possible problem areas:

```
mutex.WaitOne();
mutex.ReleaseMutex();
```

So your first label update will look like this:

```
mutex.WaitOne();
lblPlatformsUnIdentified.Text = unidentified.ToString();
mutex.ReleaseMutex();
```

Comment: He knows where an exception could be thrown, he asks why isn't that exception being caught in that `catch` block.

Comment: Maybe because multiple threads are crashing at the same time so it never gets caught?  Or the crash is not caused by a handled exception?

Comment: Now that I think of it, if you want an exception to be caught in a thread, your try/catch needs to be inside the thread.

Comment: I don't think you're right in this case - TPL handles exceptions thrown by the threads. The exceptions are collected and an AggregateException is thrown to the caller thread, which in this case, should catch it.